# Why AnimationSet does not execute animation combination properly?

Tags: android, animation

I'm having big trouble with animations sequence using AnimationSet. I want to do the following animation:

Scale up from 0 to 100% then move from A to B and at the same time alpha from 1.0 to 0.5 and 0.5 to 1.0.

I have multiple issues with this sequence but the two majors are:

- Despite the fact that I calculate the start offset and the duration of each animation properly, the move animation ends and I'm still at alpha 0.5 so it increase back to 1.0 once at position B.
- Sometimes the alpha animation does not reach 1.0 it looks like it stops at 0.9 or it reaches 1.0 and when the screen is redrawn and it is display at 0.9.

To my knowledge the AnimatorSet evaluates the animations sequentially but with startOffset it can run them in parallel.

Here's a piece of my code:

```
public void moveAndDrawPart( ImageView partToMove, Button buttonPressed )
   {
      // Save current data for listener.
      lastPartToMove    = partToMove;
      lastButtonPressed = buttonPressed;

      // Animate part movement.
      animatePart(partToMove, buttonPressed);
   }

   // Animate part movement from original position to the final position.
   private void animatePart(ImageView part, Button destination)
   {
      // Make part visible.
      part.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
      part.bringToFront();

      AnimationSet animator = new AnimationSet(false);
      animator.setFillAfter(false);

      // Make part appears by scaling up.
      ScaleAnimation scaleUp = new ScaleAnimation((float)0.0, (float)1.0, (float)0.0, (float)1.0, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
      scaleUp.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
      scaleUp.setFillAfter(true);
      scaleUp.setStartOffset(0);
      scaleUp.setDuration(500);      

      // Move from origin to final position.
      TranslateAnimation move = new TranslateAnimation(0, destination.getX()-part.getX(), 0, destination.getY()-part.getY());
      move.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
      move.setFillAfter(true);
      move.setStartOffset(scaleUp.getDuration());
      move.setDuration(600);

      // Make part semi-transparent.
      AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation((float)1.0, (float)0.5);
      alpha.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
      alpha.setFillAfter(true);
      alpha.setRepeatCount(1);
      alpha.setRepeatMode(AlphaAnimation.REVERSE);
      alpha.setStartOffset(scaleUp.getDuration());
      alpha.setDuration(300);

      animator.addAnimation(scaleUp);
      animator.addAnimation(move);
      animator.addAnimation(alpha);
      animator.setAnimationListener(this);

      part.startAnimation(animator);
   }

   // Reposition part at final position to redraw it properly.
   private void repositionPart(ImageView part, Button destination)
   {
      // Clear part animation to bring back drawn position to original.
      part.clearAnimation();

      part.setX(destination.getX());
      part.setY(destination.getY());
   }

   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
   {
      // This variable is used to workaround a glitch: clearAnimation() 
      // causes onAnimationEnd() to be called twice.
      animationDone = false;
   }

   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
   {
      // This variable is used to workaround a glitch: clearAnimation() 
      // causes onAnimationEnd() to be called twice.
      if(animationDone == false)
      {
         animationDone = true;

         if( (lastPartToMove != null) && (lastButtonPressed != null) )
         {
            // Reposition the part.
            repositionPart(lastPartToMove, lastButtonPressed);
         }
         else
         {
            Toast.makeText(myAct, "Major error occured. Last references are not set!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
      }
   }
```

Could you tell me why AnimationSet doesn't do what I'm expecting?

By the way, I'm experimenting this issue with the Honeycomb 3.2 emulator.

Comment: Concerning the alpha that sometime doesn't reach 1.0 at the end of the animation. I tested it on a device and got the same result until I activate the hardware acceleration in my application. From now on, the alpha seems to always reach 1.0. However, I still get the weird behaviour on the emulator.

Comment: Did anyone has a chance to try my code and see if it glitches?

Answer (score 0):

after you create you animation or animation set you must load it to a View kind class like Layout.
then you can animate that layout like this:

```
 TranslateAnimation trans = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, height/2);
        trans.setDuration(1000);


        myAnimationSet.addAnimation(trans);

        final RelativeLayout splash_relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_splash);
        splash_relative.startAnimation(myAnimationSet);
```

and it works. i hope it's help.